# fog effect using the smoke particle template

Tags: swift, arkit, particle-system

i'm looking to create a fog effect that will surround a building, this is a 3d model. I'm trying to use the built in smoke template to achieve this, but have been unable to get the desired effect. Is it possible to load in external particle effects or can you only use the templates Provided?. Has anyone managed to create a fong effect using the smoke template?